# Realtek wireless adapter randomly disables

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, network-adapter, wireless-adapter

I have a laptop with a Clevo P150EM motherboard and Realtek RTL8723AE wireless adapter running Windows 10 Professional.

I am occasionally able to connect to a wireless network and connect to the internet but the adapter seems to randomly disconnect and disable then enable itself after roughly 20 minutes. When this happens I am unable to reconnect to the network without rebooting the machine.

Sometimes when I try to connect to a network, the connection will be attempted then the adapter disables and enables, stopping the connection from happening.

I have updated all drivers, uninstalled and reinstalled latest drivers, tried everything [suggested by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10741/windows-10-fix-network-connection-issues) including turning off the turn off adapter to save power option.

There are several other devices connected to the router that work fine, including Windows 10 devices.

I have exhausted the options presented in the Microsoft forums, most of which just point to solutions in the link above.

Does anyone know how I can get the wireless adapter to maintain a stable connection.

Answer (score 0):

First, where is the laptop? Have you tried to move it closer to the router to determine if a weak signal (e.g. blocked or reflected by a wall) or interference is the cause of the issue?

Second, try another OS to determine if it is the wireless adapter itself at fault or Windows OS: create a bootable USB drive with another OS (e.g. [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download), probably 64-bit desktop version) and operate directly from the USB -- no need to install the OS. If operating that way still demonstrates the issue, the it's a hardware problem. Easier than fixing the internal adapter might be using a [USB wireless adapter, available from US$9 and up](https://www.amazon.com/USB-Computer-Network-Adapters/b). However, if dropouts cease under the test OS, you know it's a Windows issue.

Comment: It's about half a metre from the router. The adapter has worked under a previous install of Windows 10. This is a new install from scratch so I'm guessing it's a software problem.